# How does Python receive a string from a C function?

Tags: python, c++

C code:

```
#include "Python.h"
#include <windows.h>
__declspec(dllexport) PyObject* getTheString()
{
    auto p = Py_BuildValue("s","hello");
    char * s = PyString_AsString(p);
    MessageBoxA(NULL,s,"s",0);
    return p;
}
```

Python code:

```
import ctypes
import sys
sys.path.append('./')
dll = ctypes.CDLL('pythonCall_test.dll')
print type(dll.getTheString())
```

Result:

```
<type 'int'>
```

How can I get `pytype(str)'hello'` from C code? Or is there any Pythonic way to translate this `pytype(int)` to `pytype(str)`?

It looks like no matter what I change，the returned `Pyobject*` is a `pytype(int)` no else

Comment: the messagebox shows 'hello'

Comment: Just thinking out loud: in the c code you are returning a PyObject pointer, which is just an address actually. And the python side is receiving this as an integer (since it is just an address)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> By default functions are assumed to return the C `int` type. Other
>   return types can be specified by setting the `restype` attribute of the
>   function object.
>   [(ref)](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html#return-types)

Define the type returned by your function like that:

```
>>> from ctypes import c_char_p
>>> dll.getTheString.restype = c_char_p # c_char_p is a pointer to a string
>>> print type(dll.getTheString())
```

Comment: can i return a Python type to python code? i wanna python code receive python value from C code.but thank u for the answer

Answer (score 0):

`int` is the default return type, to specify another type you need to set the function object's `restype` attribute. See [Return types](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html#return-types) in the `ctype` docs for details.